# No sound "Dymmy output"

Tags: sound

I have asus laptop, some time after installation ubuntu 18.10 my sound disappeared and now I see "Dummy output" on sound output device.
I tried to change kernels, it helped me for the first restart, after second restart got dummy output again.
If I try connect any earphones its dont work and I still have no sound.

Comment: Dummy output is not a real output, it is meant as a loopback for desktop audio. there are a plethora of solutions for your problem. start by going into BIOS and disableing onboard audio, booting to your ubuntu, reboot to bios again then turn onboard audio back on an boot one last time to ubuntu, as indicated here: https://askubuntu.com/a/948383/307184 does that fix it? if not how about following this guide : https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html ?

Comment: I dont have "onboard audio" in my bios

Comment: then try the second.

Comment: didnt help me too.