# Dummy output device after connecting to hdmi

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I am on ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, HP spectre x360. I connected a monitor through an USB c to HDMI adapter. And then connected an USB enable cable between my laptop and monitor so that I can connect mouse and keyboard to monitor.

After that, I am unable to use my speakers and getting dummy output. Screenshot attached.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pxEj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Dummy Output" No sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: no, I tried it but it didn't work. I can't see my sound card in `pacmd list-cards` @David

Comment: I get following error ```$ start-pulseaudio-x11 
Failure: Module initialization failed```