# Sound not working on ubuntu 20.04. I just see Dummy output in sound settings

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently installed ubuntu 20.04 lts on my acer swift 3 laptop. Seems the sound is not working.

In sound settings, I just see Dummy output.

here is the output of `hwinfo --sound`

```
17: PCI 1f.3: 0401 Multimedia audio controller                  
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: nS1_.8YazuRdW485
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "Intel Multimedia audio controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x34c8 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1025 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x136d 
  Revision: 0x30
  Driver: "sof-audio-pci"
  Driver Modules: "snd_sof_pci"
  Memory Range: 0x601d160000-0x601d163fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x601d000000-0x601d0fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 164 (14 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d000034C8sv00001025sd0000136Dbc04sc01i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: snd_sof_pci is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_sof_pci"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
reyansh@acer:~$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

Also, I see no soundcards were found!

```
reyansh@acer:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards ---
```

And, the output of `lspci -v` for sound is,

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 164
    Memory at 601d160000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 601d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Dummy Output" No sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I tried, it says No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

Comment: I guess the problem here is Capabilities: <access denied>. I don't know how to fix.

Comment: when I run the command alsamixer, it gives the following output: cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

Comment: I fixed the sound issue, but the internal microphone is not working. In sound settings, the Input Device has no options to choose. But when I plug in the earphones with mic, the microphone from the earphone is detected. How do I fix this?

Comment: Good to know that you fixed that! For the microphone issue I suggest that you ask a new question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a fix. Run the following command.

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Now, reload alsa and reboot.

```
sudo killall pulseaudio 
sudo alsa force-reload
sudo reboot
```

Comment: worked for me with ubuntu 20.04 / lenovo ideapad Slim 7-15IMH05

Comment: worked for me on acer swift 3

Comment: this worked for me :)

Comment: worked also on debian bookworm/sid thanks !