# How to install a soundcard (snd-hda-intel) while being offline

Tags: apt, package-management, sound, lubuntu, alsa

I  have a computer with no access to internet, however, lubuntu 18.04 (also tried with lubuntu 20.04) does not produce sound. It keeps saying "no dummy output". While on a computer with internet access I downloaded "Cube-Get" and downloaded the DKMS package , which included all of the dependencies. I moved the dependencies for the dkms package on to a USB and transferred it to my computer with no internet. While installing , it halted because of broken dependencies.

The reason im installing dkms package is because I need the snd-hda-intel driver.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can navigate this problem?

Comment: Without specific messages we cannot really help.  Some commands require all dependencies to be pre-installed (as it cannot go the web to download missing packages) for example, if your install failed because you tried to install a package built for another release (eg. a *focal* package that will work on 20.04, but have *dep* issues on *bionic* (18.04)  that would be expected) you've provided no specifics for us to help with.  FYI:   I would expect intel cards (`snd-hda-intel`) to work anyway; but we have few details.. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS with what stack? GA kernel? HWE kernel? and which kernel?

Comment: Did you downloaded packages match your 18.04 system?   Most just downloaded packages will assume a fully-updated system, so was yours?  With regards the kernel, GA is provided with 18.04 & 18.04.1 (ie. 4.15 kernel), 18.04.2 came with 4.18, 18.04.3 came with 5.0, 18.04.4 with 5.3 kernel, 18.04.5 with 5.4 kernel - so was did your dkms kernel downloads match the system you installed? (or did you fully-upgrade it via usb-thumb-drive?)  We currently don't know  (a fully upgraded GA/general system remains on 4.15, where as HWE upgrades the kernel & stack until it reaches the final 5.4/focal)

Comment: Another FYI:   My box uses the `snd_hda_intel` *kernel module* for it's sound, and I've not needed to install anything on any releases from 14.04 (*trusty*) up to current *hirsute* (what will be Lubuntu 21.04 when it's released).  Same for other boxes that use the intel cards; as intel add the code needed to the open source linux kernel (usually only newer high-end graphics needs special drivers, or cheap wireless)

Comment: If you want to ask about your sound issue, we'd require details about your sound card. Me I tend to use `sudo lshw -C sound` where `sudo` elevates privileges, `lshw` will list-hardware and -C limits output to 'sound' devices.  My own output includes the detail `driver=snd_hda_intel` meaning I'm already using the snd_hda_intel kernel module (ie. *driver* in non-OS tech speak).  That driver is generic & open source.

Comment: Hi, sorry to hear that. Could you share the steps you did when downloading and installing a package via CubeGet if you don't mind?

Also, you might give this a try:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04