# No sound from the default/on board audio hardware on Ubuntu 18.04 with Dell Latitude 3510

Tags: sound, xubuntu, dell

I have bought this Dell Latitude 3510 with Ubuntu 18.04 Pre-installed. After 6 days of purchase I am having issues in audio output. I have installed software of what I need for my works. Idk which software cause this issue but my audio on the device isn't working. It was working till 5th day but not working now. I visited the dealer who sold me this laptop, but they don't have engineers who can work with Ubuntu :(

On board Audio is not working however, if any device attached with Bluetooth, it works.

[image]

I tried following this solution but it didn't work for me. [dummy output no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04).

Can anyone please help me? I don't want to re install Ubuntu or do anything that will harm my data.

--------------------------
Adding output of the mentioned commands

```
$ uname -a
Linux hemant-Latitude-3510 5.4.0-74-generic #83~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 11 16:01:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
hemant@hemant-Latitude-3510:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards ---
hemant@hemant-Latitude-3510:~$ dpkg -L linux-modules-$(uname -r)-generic | grep snd
dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-5.4.0-74-generic-generic' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
hemant@hemant-Latitude-3510:~$ inxi -SA

Command 'inxi' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install inxi

hemant@hemant-Latitude-3510:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -n -A 4 Audio
hemant@hemant-Latitude-3510:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
hemant@hemant-Latitude-3510:~$ sudo lshw -C multimedia
[sudo] password for hemant: 
  *-usb:1                   
       description: Video
       product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
       vendor: CNFHH47R052430381E70
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       version: 83.30
       capabilities: usb-2.01
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci latency=64
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:134 memory:6001118000-600111bfff memory:6001000000-60010fffff
hemant@hemant-Latitude-3510:~$ dpkg -l | grep alsa
ii  alsa-base                                  1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                            all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.1.3-1ubuntu1                                  amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                    1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.3                         amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
hemant@hemant-Latitude-3510:~$ sudo alsa force-reload

Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-skl-hda-dsp snd-soc-hdac-hdmi snd-soc-dmic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-sof-pci snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof-intel-byt snd-sof-intel-ipc snd-sof snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-skl-hda-dsp snd-soc-hdac-hdmi snd-soc-dmic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-sof-pci snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof-intel-byt snd-sof-intel-ipc snd-sof snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible sources of the problem are quite a few.
One possibility (perhaps my first guess) is a drivers issue.
To begin with, you should post the output of some commands to start diagnosis.
Check [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul)

Post the output (or any other observation you consider relevant) of

```
$ uname -a
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
$ dpkg -L linux-modules-$(uname -r)-generic | grep snd
$ inxi -SA
$ lspci -nnk | grep -n -A 4 Audio
$ aplay -l
$ sudo lshw -C multimedia
$ dpkg -l | grep alsa
$ sudo alsa force-reload
```

As a first guess, try installing and then reboot

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```