# Speakers working but not working

Tags: drivers, sound, 18.04, speakers, output

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and for some reason my speakers are not listed among the available sound devices, there's only the headphones. 
Given the situation i installed pavucontrol and there I found the speakers, marked as unavailable though, but as I chose them they worked perfectly. So the speakers work but they are unavailable in the sound options, does anyone have an idea of what might be going on?

Comment: Not quite sure if you've already answered your question, but you should use pavucontrol to set your speakers as a default for apps. Or I am missing something?

Comment: Hey there, yup if I choose it from pavucontrol I get them to work but they still do not appear listed in the sound settings, so as I open the sound settings the headphones take over again, was hoping on a possible permanent solution rather than this temporary one, a way I can make it get listed among the sound units...

Comment: Could you check and confirm if these given answers provide a solution? https://askubuntu.com/questions/398030/change-default-sound-device