# Sound problem (16.04)

Tags: sound

After using an external microphone and now having unplugged it my sound does not work any more.
The command

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

gives "unable to connect".

Typing

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

plays sound, but says

```
Home directory not accessible: Keine Berechtigung
Home directory not accessible: Keine Berechtigung
Wiedergabe: WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate: 48000 Hz, mono
```

And

```
sudo addgroup <myusername> audio
```

gives that the user is already member of the group.

Comment: With `pulseaudio --start` the problem is temporarily removed, after reboot it appears again.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338382/pulseaudio-not-working-home-directory-not-accessible-permission-denied) would be helpful.

Comment: First : [Solve your problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398030/change-default-sound-device) Then, [Save Changes in PulseAudio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361403/sound-settings-not-saved-in-pulse-audio-gnome-how-to-save-them) Good luck :)