# No sound in built in speakers just "dummy output" as output device

Tags: sound, xubuntu

I've tried

```
$ echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
$ echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
$ echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

and

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
$ sudo alsa force-reload

and

$ sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
```

and

added snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 in /etc/default/grub with no luck

Xubuntu detects the  HDMI sound hardware and the mic.

Here is the output for some commands about the system, hardware and modules.

```
$ uname -a
Linux Mordor 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:25:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [1002:9840]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [103c:81fe]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
00:09.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge [1022:157d]
00:09.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller [1022:157a]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller [103c:81fe]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel


$ lsmod | grep audio
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek

$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    90112  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

[image: HDMI sound hardware is detected]

Comment: See if this has a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks! your comment head me to the solution!

Comment: You're most welcome and welcome to **Ask Ubuntu**. Don't forget to accept your answer as the correct solution in two days time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved choosing the right default sound card following this solution  [Changing default sound card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398030/change-default-sound-device)