# Ubuntu 20.04 Dell Inspiron 3000 on-board audio not being detected

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, dell, alsa

This is a fresh install of 20.04 on a Dell Inspiron 3000.

The system will detect an external headset and hdmi as an output/input, however, it will not detect the internal speakers/mic.

Kernal - `5.12.10-051210-generic`

Sound driver - `Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.12.10-051210-generic.`

```
    Subsystem: Dell Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 76
    Memory at c06c8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    Subsystem: Dell Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 69
    Memory at c0680000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_pci_acp3x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x

04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Dell Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 77
    Memory at c06c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Running `alsamixer` shows two options of **0  HD-Audio Generic** and **1  HD-Audio Generic**, but none of these seem to do anything.

Any ideas on where to look next would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the exact command you used to produce the output?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try the following ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238292/226614)).

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and append `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0`.

   (An alternative option `snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` [was proposed](https://superuser.com/a/1532663/245595), you may try whatever works.)
2. Update `grub` configuration with

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot

I expect this to work, compare audio specs of [the system in the source OP](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/es-ar/g-series-15-3590-laptop/dell-g3-3590-setup-and-specifications/audio?guid=guid-ad5b9aba-9b9b-44a5-8988-23aea8d10df6&lang=en-us) and [the present one](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/es-ar/inspiron-15-3567-laptop/inspiron-15-3567-setup-specifications/audio?guid=guid-a30a4421-a560-44a5-a475-d6bbcd04d380&lang=en-us).
It is worth reading the other answers and comments in the same question.

You might be getting the same result with

```
$ echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

(or the alternative

```
$ echo "options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

as per item 1 above)

---

If the above doesn't work, further info on your system may help.
Please post the exact output of all the commands listed in [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul) (and, to be sure, the commands themselves as you wrote them).

**Related**:

1. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251157
2. [Ubuntu 19.10 Audio driver issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218058/ubuntu-19-10-audio-driver-issue/1238287#1238287%5D%5B1%5D)
3. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=314511
4. [No sound in built in speakers just "dummy output" as output device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312142/no-sound-in-built-in-speakers-just-dummy-output-as-output-device)
5. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205959

Comment: your 4. source is useless - I know that it wont work because he says he doesn't have dummy selected

Comment: @france1 - I don't see what you say.