# WINE discard alsamixer settings, uses screen as speakers

Tags: sound, 14.04, wine, alsa

As I run programs in `wine-1.6.2` my screen speakers will be used as default. The default, as changed via `alsamixer`, is to disable the screen speakers and allow all other sound to flow freely (auto mute: disabled). I have no idea why this happens.

I run Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I have no special sound drivers installed. I don't really know how to troubleshoot this issue so I don't have any further information.

Comment: Did you try to run winecfg ? It has a "audio" tab to select wine audio input/output.

Comment: Yes I did that. Tried all available options but none of them made a difference.

Comment: I also have wine (1.5.20) with playonlinux sometimes set my default Speakers to HDMI output. In debug mode it says, wine cannot map stereo output to surround SPeakers, therefore setting default to stereo speakers. don't know what that means and how to handle it...

Comment: That's helpful. Unfortunatly my computer only support HDMI and DVI whereas my screen support HDMI and VGA. I'm stuck with HDMI :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue using the following [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line) and changing my "default output sink".