# Screencam that records sound (2014)

Tags: sound, screencast

It's 2014.

What's the best tool for recording a session on my computer that includes internal audio?

Comment: What do you mean by internal audio?

Comment: I mean audio generated by the programs running. Not the microphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use this command in terminal

```
   avconv -f   pulse -i default -f x11grab -r 15 -s $(xdpyinfo  | grep dimensions | awk -F ' ' ' { print $2 } ' ) -i :0.0+0,0 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264  $(date +"%m%d%Y_%H%M%S_$HOSTNAME")_screencast.mp4
```

If you want a sophisticated one try this http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/

[image]

It's open source and looks nice.

EDIT:

For inline audio try this

```
pavucontrol
```

then switch to **output devices** then click on green check mark with tooltip `Set as fallback`

Comment: I like the command line solution nice. But doesn't pick up internal audio. Just the microphone. :-(

Comment: how come? It records internal voice in my case. You may need to play with audio settings.

Comment: You would need to set the default source in PulseAudio as the Monitor of Builtin Analog Stereo (see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line)). That should make this work.

Comment: I have used SimpleScreenRecorder and for me, it is the best for video + audio screencast on Linux today. It is lightweight, stable, but can produce good quality video. I recommend it for you.

Comment: Ah ... but that simplescreenrecorder worked a treat. :-)

Comment: I guess what I was really looking for was a screenrecorder that could work out what audio I was trying to record. And the default of SSR (unlike recordmydesktop etc.) seemed to have figured it out.

Comment: @interstar
For inline audio try this: pavucontrol > output devices then click on green check mark with tooltip Set as fallback

Answer (score 1):

Try [vokoscreen](http://www.kohaupt-online.de/hp):

1. Install it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vokoscreen
   ```
2. Check Settings

   [image: vokoscreen - display settings]
   [image: vokoscreen - sound settings]
3. *Start*

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try Kazam:

[image: Kazam]

I've never used it thoroughly (it didn't work on my computer, but that's probably because I have a special audio setup), but it looks like if you check the "Sound from Speakers" option, it will record what you're looking for.