# 20.04 Sound Device Reverts to Headphones on Each Restart

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, headphones

When I switch my output device to speakers, everything works as expected. Until I reboot the machine. Then I have to go back into settings and select my speaker output again because Ubuntu reverts to using my headphones for output.

While I use the headset infrequently, I leave it plugged in all the time. Unplugging the headset is a bit of a chore due to the design on my PC.

How can I force pulseaudio to always use speaker output except for when I explicitly select the headphones for audio output? Right now it's the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulseaudio is configurable. To find out, which sources you have you could issue:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

Then you might get something like:

```
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED
```

To set a certain output as default (your choice from the list above):

```
pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

To persist it put that line into
`/etc/pulse/default.pa`to have it across reboots

Comment: This solution did not work for me. After adding the suggested line (edited to match my device), I lost all sound output devices. Removing the line from the configuration file restored expected functionality.

Comment: The reason your solution did not work was because I copied and pasted the last bit of code and put my sink name in there. I did not even notice that the line started with `pacmd'. Removing that first bit from the configuration line fixed the issue. Pulseaudio is behaving exactly as I wanted now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various searches, I was able to solve my issue following steps outlined [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line).

After identifying the correct device using `pacmd list-sinks`, I added the command `pacmd set-default-sink "SINKNAME"` to Startup Applications.

Since I wanted to explicitly set the headset as the output device only when I was using it, this solution worked for my issue.

Edit: This solution is not perfect as the output device will revert back to headphones if pulseaudio is restarted. But it beats having to change the device every time I reboot the system.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing. I'd be interested in your pactl list .. and which source you entered

Comment: @kanehekili I had two entries: My USB headset, and my onboard audio: `alsa_card.usb-Cosair_Corsair_VOID_PRO_Surround_USB_Adapter_00000000-00` and `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo`. I used the latter for the startup command.

Comment: I've borked it and edited my answer. I was on the "wrong side". You'd needed sinks, not sources. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

List your devices by name

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

Set default output device in the config file:

```
echo "set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-000_00_05.0.analog-stereo" >> /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

**Replace <alsa_output.pci-000_00_05.0.analog-stereo> with your device of choice from above device listings**

Reboot system.